# Count the number of times a specific value occurs in each column

Tags: bash

I've seen many similar solutions to my question, but I can't find one that quite covers my particular need. I have data that look like this:

```
meal1 apple -1 -1 -1 0
meal2 orange 0 0 -1 0
meal3 banana -1 0 -1 0
```

I want to count the number of times that -1 occurs within each column. My desired result looks like this:

```
0 0 2 1 3 0
```

I found an awk solution here: [Count the occurences of a number in all the columns in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60871866/count-the-occurences-of-a-number-in-all-the-columns-in-bash) but I'm not very familiar with awk and am unsure how to account for the - in my target. There must be a way to do this with bash?

Added context: When I use the solution in the linked answer, but replace instances of 1 with -1, I get an error in awk ("fatal: attempt to access field -1"). I'm guessing this error is caused by something very basic, but like I mentioned above, I'm not very familiar with awk and would like to understand the solution I'm applying.

Comment: With your linked answer: `awk '{ for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) { if($i == -1) { ++c[i]; } } } 
  END{ for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) { printf "%d%s", c[i], i!=NF ? OFS : ORS; } }' file`

Comment: Why do you think `-1` will be any different from `1`? Just change `$i == 1` to `$i == -1`.